# Using mod_rewrite for a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making the SEO's more user friendly for a website and through here I discovered mod_rewrite. I've written up some code based on what I saw but before I put it in the .htaccess file I want to ensure that it looks proper. I really don't want to be messing around with a .htaccess file on a live site so I was basically just looking for some reassurance that this code looks ok to use.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^case-study-cff-campaign/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=10      
RewriteRule ^case-study-prohockeymindset/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=14    
RewriteRule ^case-study-CFNU-convention-2013/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=16    
RewriteRule ^case-study-CFNU-research-to-action/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=19    
RewriteRule ^case-study-Accountapotamus/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=21    
RewriteRule ^case-study-Balance-Relaxation-Therapy/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=23    
RewriteRule ^case-study-PQCHC/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=25    
RewriteRule ^case-study-ULTC/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=27    
RewriteRule ^case-study-Community-Forward-Fund/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=269    
RewriteRule ^case-study-Chartier-Physiotherapy/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code looks ok to use in an htaccess file or a `<Directory>` container because the leading slash is stripped off in those cases. In server or vhost, you'll need a leading slash in front of all of them.

Also, you may want to add the `L` flag or the `QSA` flag so you don't lose query string parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^case-study-cff-campaign/?$      casestudy.php?casestudyid=10 [L,QSA]
```

for each of your rules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply on this. I was just a little nervous about modifying the .htaccess file. I've heard some horror stories about the smallest changes resulting in the weirdest things happening. I'll be sure to add the tags to the code and then upload the.htaccess file. thanks again.

Comment: @Shawntaulicus The order of rewrite rules matter, so if you have rules in your htaccess file already, then you'll need to make sure to have them in the right order. The rules you have need to be **before** any rules that look like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ...` and **after** any rules that have the `R` flag